# Bootstrap dropdown have not shown whats wrong?

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TutupLapak</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Announcement
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/posts"> View Announcement</a></li>
              <li><a href="/posts/create"> Create Post</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/services">Category</a></li>
          <li><a href="/posts"> View Announcement</a></li>
          <li><a href="/posts/create"> Create Post</a></li>
        </ul>
          <!--<a href="/posts"> View Announcement </a></li>--> <!-- posts folder define on root web -->
          <!--<a href="/posts/create"> Create Post</a></li>-->
     </div>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

**i try to create a dropdown list, but the list doesnt show (view announcement and create post)**
anything i am doing wrong in this code ? i am new at this

Comment: You are closing one div to many (`</div>`). Apart from that, it works as, so you might be missing some js or css file bootstrap needs. https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/c12Lg9xp/

Comment: thankyou man i miss some bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i test your code that run without any issue, you have two menu called create Post and view announcement, and also a menu called Announcement with two submenu called create post and view announcement, check your css and js files again.